# Insert into with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, insert-into

I am messing around with some things in a test database and came across something I would like to do. In the future I will have to update some information in one table with new dates and budget info. Here is my code...

```
USE REPORTING
DECLARE
@JAN MONEY = 100.00

INSERT INTO FACTBUDGET (BUDGETAMOUNT)

SELECT
CASE WHEN BUDGETDATEID > 20141231 AND BUDGETDATEID < 20150201 AND MISCID = 0 
THEN @JAN
ELSE 'BUDGET NEEDED'
END AS BUDGETDATEID

FROM FACTBUDGET
```

When I run this the variable goes into that column but to almost all records. Am i doing this the easiest way? I was thinking of creating a temp table but thought that would be too much data to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do an `update`?

```
UPDATE FACTBUDGET
    SET BUDGETAMOUNT = @JAN
    WHERE BUDGETDATEID > 20141231 AND BUDGETDATEID < 20150201 AND MISCID = 0 ;
```

Comment: I think that will work great but why won't my method work as well?

Comment: @MatthewJakachira . . . You are inserting new rows into the table, which is quite different from updating existing rows.

Comment: That actually makes sense when I think about it further and you say it so simply. Sorry for the inconvenience. I need to set aside some more time to get to really know sql.  thanks for the help

Comment: In additional to the insert/update issue, there may be an error caused by the `CASE` statement because the result_expressions (the values returned after `THEN` and `ELSE`) have different datatypes. `@JAN` is  `MONEY` and `'BUDGET NEEDED'` is `char`. SQL SERVER will convert the result from the `CASE` statement to the [type with highest precedent](bit.ly/1YNcvdL) among the different datatypes included as possible results. If you ran just the SELECT query w/o the INSERT part, you may have gotten the error "Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."